Как управляя своим аккаунтом дискорда отправлять сообщения другу на python?
Мне надо что бы бот автоматически писал другу раз в день одно сообщение с моего аккаунта.

вопрос по типу "напишите код за меня".
Хочу вам сказать, что создание ботов, который используют аккаунт обычного пользователя, а не бота запрещены. Создание такого может привести к бану вашего аккаунта.

нет, я искал как можно рассылать сообщения в дискорде и знаю что это запрещено правилами и то что может заблокировать мой аккаунт, но я не смог найти того как выполнить функцию отправки сообщений в лс, по этой причине обратился сюда.
Если бы я знал как это написать или была бы хоть какая-то документация об этом я бы уже это сделал и сюда бы не обращался, но такого нету.

Попробуйте поискать здесь, может найдете ваше решение. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418496/discord-py-how-do-i-send-private-message-to-someone-using-the-persons-id
